# How to select all latest model entries based on an attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :key, :value
end
```

Given this Log table:

```
id: 1, key: "apple", value: "tasty", 
id: 2, key: "apple", value: "green",  
id: 3, key: "apple", value: "sour",  
id: 4, key: "orange", value: "juicy",  
id: 5, key: "orange", value: "round",  
id: 6, key: "banana", value: "yellow",
```

I want a **scope** that returns the last log for each unique key, namely logs with id `3, 5, 6` affirming that apples are sour, oranges are round and bananas - yellow.

I would like to do this on the database side, but lacking knowledge I can only imagine a ruby-side solution with an inefficient loop

```
Log.all.pluck(:key).uniq.map {|key| Log.where(key: key).last }
```

Needless to say, looping over all unique keys would grow slow as table content increases and, most importantly, would return an array, not ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Can this even be done with SQL?

Comment: Cute, but this is a trivialized example. The actual database has hundreds of keys in random order.

Comment: What have you done/tried?

Comment: @Epigene Replace 3,5,6 with the keys that were generated in random order

Comment: @emaillenin Model.find only works with id, not arbitrary key. Besides, I know neither the ids, not the keys I am looking for. All I know is that the Log model stores many key-value pairs and I need an algorithm that finds the last entry of all keys.

Comment: as an aside, you don't need that `attr_accessible` statement, as active record creates these for each column

Comment: @Yule attr_accessible != attr_accessor, but, sure, put it there just to show what fields the example model has.

Comment: oh yeah, misread - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the calculate method in active record: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate 
Your example pretty much matches the example given there:

```
values = Log.group(:key).maximum(:id)
```

But this would only give you a hash of key-values. You could then pluck the ID and pass it into a where:

```
values = Log.where(id: Log.group(:key).maximum(:id).values)
```

This would still do two queries, but it's still better than looping through all, and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Log.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT(key) FROM logs
ORDER BY created_at DESC")
```

Comment: On to something, but this seems to only return the Logs' id and key fields, where I need all attributes.